# option menu button is not showing when use theme of main activity NoActionBar

Tags: java, android

I am using theme of main activity , but option menu is not showing . please tell how to show option menu with this theme, please tell me about this issue

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

This is my java code . it will fine whan I change the theme to other like dark action bar please tell me what can I do

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_setting, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            // write your code here

            return true;

        case 2:
            // write your code here
            return true;

        case 3:
            // write your code here
            return true;

        case 4:
            // write your code here
            return true;

        case 5:
            // write your code here
            return true;

        case 6:
            // write your code here
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is my xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
    android:id="@+id/Timer"
    android:title="@string/timer"/>
   <item
    android:id="@+id/friends"
    android:title="@string/night_mode"/>
   <item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:title="@string/quiz_type"/>
   </menu>
```

Comment: why don't you use toolbar instead of actionbar which is more customizable.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `NoActionBar` theme, so there's no action bar in your `activity`. In order to show your menu in your activity, the best method is adding `Toolbar` as your actionbar as [this Google Guide - Set up the app bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up):

```
// add toolbar to your layout xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>


// set toolbar as actionbar in your activity
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- After setting your theme to NoActionBar Add a custom Toolbar like below. -->
<!-- And then add the line below inside your imports -->
<!-- import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar; -->

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#02443B"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

****Then do this below your onCreate the option menu will appear****

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar4);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).